# ext.js 5.1.0 scroll issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

This might be a bit weird question to put here, the problem is I am new to an application running in ext js 5.0.1. There is an existing bug, when any input fields of a form is selected, the form scrolls to the top. I after spending a long time, I could not find out exactly where the scroll is being triggered from.

I also understand there must be some simple config to resolve this issue, but could not find that out.

I am using Google Chrome `69.0.3497.100` on Windows 10, in case it is a browser dependent issue.

The structure is like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        margin: '45 0 0 0',
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'border',
        flex: 6,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            region: 'center',
            collapsible: true,
            split: true,
            activeTab: 1,
            flex: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                itemId: 'is',
                title: 'asdf',
                autoScroll: true,
                layout: 'anchor',
                active: false,
                trackResetOnLoad: false,
                defaults: {
                    padding: '10px 10px 5px 10px',
                    border: false,
                    bodyStyle: {
                        background: '#DFE9F6'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

In the form, depending on some condition, we dynamically add and remove the resources.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fts5drh/1) link to the reproducible issue.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce issue in fiddle provided by you. Can you please check fiddle again?

Comment: @AvinashT. I checked now...it was getting scrolled up, can you please scroll down to the bottom part and click any of the checkboxes?

Comment: @SamGhatak As you mentioned ` scroll down to the bottom part and click any of the checkboxes` I have tried same it's working fine. it is not going to scroll up. In which browser you are getting this issue and also provide the version browser as well.

Comment: Sorry, should have thought about the browser issue and mentioned it...I am using Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100...let me add this to the post

Comment: @NarendraJadhav . as you guessed, it works fine in firefox 62

Comment: Can not reproduce

Comment: @Akrion in chrome 69?

Comment: Yes it is. `69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` to be exact

Comment: @SamGhatak I have also same `Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` it's working fine in that.

Comment: thats weird!!! let me check and update the post if I find anything...thanks anyway guys